# charts_flutter : Resize the Line chart within a SizedBox

Tags: flutter

I'm using charts_flutter for drawing a Line chart. but I couldn't able to resize within a sized box.
Please help me out. whenever I'm giving size, the chart is not displaying. otherwise, it's taking full-screen width and height.

```
SizedBox(
    width: 130.0,
    height: 130.0,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                        'Daily Sales',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Expanded(
                      child: charts.LineChart(
                        _seriesLineData,
                        defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(
                            includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                        animate: true,
                        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                        behaviors: [
    new charts.ChartTitle('Days',
        behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
        titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
    new charts.ChartTitle('Sales',
        behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.start,
        titleOutsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
    new charts.ChartTitle('Departments',
        behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.end,
        titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea,
        )   
  ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `FittedBox`

```
SizedBox(
  width: 130, 
  height: 130,
  child: FittedBox(child: Column(...))
)
```